# How to calculate mean and standard deviation given a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have PySpark DataFrame (**not pandas**) called `df` that is quite large to use `collect()`. Therefore the below-given code is not efficient. It was working with a smaller amount of data, however now it fails.

```
import numpy as np

myList = df.collect()
total = []
for product,nb in myList:
    for p2,score in nb:
            total.append(score)
mean = np.mean(total)
std = np.std(total)
```

Is there any way to get `mean` and `std` as two variables by using `pyspark.sql.functions` or similar?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean as mean_, std as std_
```

I could use `withColumn`, however, this approach applies the calculations row by row, and it does not return a single variable.

**UPDATE:**

Sample content of `df`:

```
+----------+------------------+
|product_PK|          products|
+----------+------------------+
|       680|[[691,1], [692,5]]|
|       685|[[691,2], [692,2]]|
|       684|[[691,1], [692,3]]|
```

I should calculate mean and standard deviation of `score` values, e.g. the value `1` in `[691,1]` is one of scores.

Comment: Can you give a sample of of your data?

Comment: @Tai: I posted a small example.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the built in functions to get aggregate statistics. Here's how to get mean and standard deviation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean as _mean, stddev as _stddev, col

df_stats = df.select(
    _mean(col('columnName')).alias('mean'),
    _stddev(col('columnName')).alias('std')
).collect()

mean = df_stats[0]['mean']
std = df_stats[0]['std']
```

Note that there are three different standard deviation functions. From the docs the one I used (`stddev`) returns the following:

> Aggregate function: returns the unbiased sample standard deviation of
>   the expression in a group

You could use the `describe()` method as well:

```
df.describe().show()
```

Refer to this link for more info: [pyspark.sql.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)

**UPDATE**: This is how you can work through the nested data.

Use `explode` to extract the values into separate rows, then call `mean` and `stddev` as shown above.

Here's a MWE:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, udf, mean as _mean, stddev as _stddev

# mock up sample dataframe
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [(680, [[691,1], [692,5]]), (685, [[691,2], [692,2]]), (684, [[691,1], [692,3]])],
    ["product_PK", "products"]
)

# udf to get the "score" value - returns the item at index 1
get_score = udf(lambda x: x[1], IntegerType())

# explode column and get stats
df_stats = df.withColumn('exploded', explode(col('products')))\
    .withColumn('score', get_score(col('exploded')))\
    .select(
        _mean(col('score')).alias('mean'),
        _stddev(col('score')).alias('std')
    )\
    .collect()

mean = df_stats[0]['mean']
std = df_stats[0]['std']

print([mean, std])
```

Which outputs:

```
[2.3333333333333335, 1.505545305418162]
```

You can verify that these values are correct using `numpy`:

```
vals = [1,5,2,2,1,3]
print([np.mean(vals), np.std(vals, ddof=1)])
```

Explanation: Your `"products"` column is a `list` of `list`s. Calling `explode` will make a new row for each element of the outer `list`. Then grab the `"score"` value from each of the exploded rows, which you have defined as the second element in a 2-element `list`. Finally, call the aggregate functions on this new column.

Comment: Nice, thanks. However, one of difficulties is the nested data that I have. Could you please check my update?

Comment: I get an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mean' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: To solve this error, it's necessary to update the import statement as follows: `from pyspark.sql.functions import mean as _mean, stddev as _stddev`

Comment: @Markus thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: This worked out of the box with pySparkon on Hive 2.3.6 and Spark 2.4.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mean` and `stddev` from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(680, [[691,1], [692,5]]), (685, [[691,2], [692,2]]), (684, [[691,1], [692,3]])],
    ["product_PK", "products"]
)

result_df = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        'val_list',
        F.array(df.products.getItem(0).getItem(1),df.products.getItem(1).getItem(1))
    )
    .select(F.explode('val_list').alias('val'))
    .select(F.mean('val').alias('mean'), F.stddev('val').alias('stddev'))
)

print(result_df.collect())
```

which outputs:

```
[Row(mean=2.3333333333333335, stddev=1.505545305418162)]
```

You can read more about [`pyspark.sql.functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) here.

Answer (score 1):

For Standard Deviation, better way of writing is as below. We can use formatting (to 2 decimal) and using the column Alias name

```
data_agg=SparkSession.builder.appName('Sales_fun').getOrCreate()    
data=data_agg.read.csv('sales_info.csv',inferSchema=True, header=True)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

*data.select((format_number(stddev('Sales'),2)).alias('Sales_Stdev')).show()*
```

Comment: [Do not use `import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711135/5858851)

Comment: Yeah offcourse .. that's just for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `Mean` and `Std. dev` of any column then 
**The simplest way I can think of is using `agg` function**

Get the Mean of a column

```py
df.agg({'produ': 'mean'}).show()

# or you can also use 
data.agg({'balance': 'avg'}).show()
```

Get the Standard Deviation of a column

```py
data.agg({'balance': 'stddev'}).show()

# and for variance you can use
data.agg({'balance': 'variance'}).show()
```